# Problem creating a reminder with date/time in title

Tags: google-assistant, date-and-time, google-voice-actions, reminders

Using Android 9 on a Pixel 2, I can recreate this problem reliably.

Let's say currently it is January 20. I prompt Google Assistant to start making a reminder for a certain date and time, such as:

"Remind me on February 8th at 6 pm",

to which it replies:

"Okay, what's the reminder?"

If I then want to the reminder text to say something like:
"Appointment tomorrow at noon",
Google will interpret that as a new reminder set for January 21 at noon, instead of a reminder on February 8th at 6 pm saying "Appointment tomorrow at noon".

This seems like a mistake, especially since Google specifically saved the date and time of the original request and prompted me just for the reminder text.

Has anyone found a solution to this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be insurmountable.  People often want reminders of an event that will occur some time in the future.  You cannot put a time in the title without it being interpreted by Google Assistant as the time for the reminder.  Having to manually edit these makes the feature much less useful.  Perhaps a keyword before a time in the title is necessary.